# Embed Google Drive in Google Site

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

I am developing a Google Site that display different kinds of Data and soon integrating with files that is connected in Google Drive and this is where my question goes. As far as I know to import a Google Drive by doing this.

```
Selected Google Site > Edit > Insert > Then Select a Folder
```

and by that a list of files in my selected folder will display in my site in `List View`

Thats one solution for me. However I want also to integrate search function like a `textbox` below that `gadget` and when i search on that list of files will also show. How can I achieved that?

and also in addition how can I embed the search fucntion of Google search on that? For example I search `test` it will just not display the file that has a name of `test` but also files that contains `test`

any means of help is highly appreciated. TYSM

Comment: In a comment you say that you already saw all the reference that was mentioned in the related answer. You should include in the question what you already reviewed and tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Apps Script and deploying it as a web app then embedding it in your Google Site. According to the [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding_your_web_app_in_google_sites):

> Web apps can also be embedded in Google Sites. (These embedded web apps are sometimes called Google Sites Gadgets.)
>
> To create a script that is bound to Google Sites, visit your site, click the gear icon, then select Manage site. Click Google Apps Scripts, then Add new script. After that, the process is the same as for creating and deploying a web app as above.

For the searching purposes use the field **`fullText`** which will check the Full text of the file including name, description, content, and indexable text. See [Search for Files documents](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) for further information

```
folder.searchFiles('fullText contains "' + search + '"')
```

Useful reference:

[Search Google Drive folder from Google Site using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595910/5995040)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it seems that I`ve seen all of the reference that you had given anyways TY